# POI's HSSF dataformat - what colors are supported?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, hssf

When colorizing numbers (black for positive numbers, red for negative numbers), I usually use this snippet:

```
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("[Green]#,##0;[Red]#,##0"));
```

Ive seen some variation like this one below but Im not sure what COLOR 5 means.

```
"[BLACK]0.00;[COLOR 5]##.##"
```

What I would like to know is, what colors are suported for these color descriptors and if it is possible to provide a hex value instead? (Ive tried it, didnt work so maybe Im doing it incorrectly).

Comment: does anyone know if it is possible to set the cell color given an hex value??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe at least values listed in [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/poi/poi/3.7/poi-3.7-sources.jar!/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.java?format=ok) should be supported. They also should be backward compatible with older versions of Excel.